# Check all item in listview with huge list item?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview

I want to check about 3000 item in `listview`. This is a bit of code :

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in this.lvItem.Items)
{
    item.Checked = !item.Checked;
}
```

But listview is very slow when item is checked. Please give me some ideas to solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: My idea: why do you need 3000 items in a listview? I don't think anyone will go through it and tick one by one. They should be well grouped and organized.

Comment: Checking or unchecking 3000 items is quite fast if you do it correctly. It takes too long because the control repaints after each item checking. You need to stop painting before the for loop and repaint after the loop. This way we will have just a single repaint. Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54555131/3110834).

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem but I found why.

I had an "ItemChecked" event handler attached to my listView that was doing some heavy stuff.

I removed the eventHandler and it solved my problem.
Try removing any "ItemChecked" eventhandler and see if the speed is better.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call [`BeginUpdate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.beginupdate?view=netframework-4.7.2) before the loop and [`EndUpdate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.endupdate?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_ListView_EndUpdate) after the loop:

```
listView1.BeginUpdate();
foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
    item.Checked = true;
listView1.EndUpdate();
```

Calling `BeginUpdate` prevents the control from drawing until the `EndUpdate` method is called.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Will something like this work for you? ...when checked, add the items to a Dictionary ...when unchecked, remove from the Dictionary. Not tested code but wondering if you could do something like this:

```
Dictionary<String, ListViewItem> Dic = listView.Items 
    .Cast<ListViewItem>() 
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Text, x => x.SubItems[0].Checked);
```

You asked how to better go about it. What I am saying is on your Check Event you will want to add items to your list view. I doubt that a user will actually check all 3000, so change your code to decide how you would want to handle checked items, the example that I have given you uses Lambda expression. If not familiar, then please alter your question to reflect what it is that you actually need and/or want...

Answer (score 0):

I heard a rumor that for large list items a for loop will work faster than a foreach loop
try

```
for(int i = 0; i = < this.1vItem.Items.Count; i++)
{
//Stuff
}
```

Comment: Tested with over 25000 items,  if there is a difference between for loop and foreach it's hardly noticable.

Answer (score 0):

I also don't think it's wise to expect a user to click 3000 items. But something I did recently, when adding the items, knowing that there would never be many and by default they should be checked, is check the items **before** adding them to the list.

Something like this:

```
foreach (Recipient recipient in recipients)
{
    var item = new ListViewItem(recipient.FirstName + " " + recipient.LastName);
    item.Tag = recipient;
    item.Checked = true;
    lvRicipients.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i <= listView1.Items.Count - 1; i++)
{
     if (!listView1.Items[i].Checked)
     listView1.Items[i].Checked = true;
}
```